# HTTP parser: scraping single page application: many GETs, how to find out when the page ends

Tags: javascript, java, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, okhttp

I'm trying to parse this site:

```
https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=java&where=usa&stpage=1
```

In essense, it's not complicated: it's a single-page-application, you give it keywords, click search and then it displays the results - it starts with displaying only around 29 results. As you scroll down, new results get loaded.

Before loading new results, it sends a GET request to

```
https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/pagination/?q=java&where=usa&isDynamicPage=true&isMKPagination=true&page=2&total=26
```

which would result in a `JSON` reply which is a list of jobs and looks somewhat like this:

```
{"Title":"Java Developer","TitleLink":"https://job-openings.monster.com/java-developer-orlando-fl-us-summit-technologies/215193478","DatePostedText":"6 days ago","DatePosted":"2020-01-18T12:00","LocationText":"Orlando, FL, 32801","JobViewUrl":"https://job-openings.monster.com/java-developer-orlando-fl-us-summit-technologies/215193478","ImpressionTracking":"data-m_impr_uuid=\"a7320356-70db-46ca-908e-e540f0e74cec\" data-m_impr_a_placement_id=\"JSR2CW\" data-m_impr_s_t=\"t\" data-m_impr_j_p=\"27\" data-m_impr_j_jpm=\"1\" data-m_impr_j_lat=\"28.5418\" data-m_impr_j_long=\"-81.3736\" data-m_impr_j_jawsid=\"418397617\" data-m_impr_j_postingid=\"b55f4409-3858-483a-a2e9-65e254ec1cd2\" data-m_impr_j_jobid=\"215193478\" data-m_impr_j_cid=\"660\" data-m_impr_j_occid=\"11970\" data-m_impr_j_lid=\"385\" data-m_impr_j_jpt=\"1\" data-m_impr_j_pvc=\"monster\" data-m_impr_j_coc=\"xsummittechx\" ","Company":{"Name":"Summit Technologies","HasCompanyAddress":true,"LogoLink":""},"Text":"Java Developer","ApplyType":"ApplyOnline","IsAggregated":"false","JobViewUrlMeta":"https://job-openings.monster.com/java-developer-orlando-fl-us-summit-technologies/215193478","MusangKingId":"215193478","CompanyLogoUrl":"","PrivateBoardIconImageUrl":"","FitIcon":"","FitIconType":""}
```

[image]

and another POST request is sent to

```
https://ib.adnxs.com/ut/v3
```

(the v3 request):

[image]

where the value `14162549` of `tag_id: 14162549` seems to be taken from the above GET request.

So as you scroll down, it sends 1 GET and 1 POST requests, until it doesn't - the scroll ends and so do the requests:

[image]

I don't understand how it determines when to stop.

I want to scrape those jobs, and I can do something like sending GETs to

`https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/pagination/?q=java&where=usa&isDynamicPage=true&isMKPagination=true&page=N`

but I wouldn't know when to stop, because if say, it stops scrolling when `&page=12`, if I send a request to `&page=13`, it wouldn't return an empty JSON, on the contrary, it would show some other jobs (maybe less relevant and therefore not visible when scrolling to the bottom).

I use `okHttp` to send requests, like this:

```
HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(getUrl()).newBuilder();
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("page", "1");
String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        .addHeader("Accept-Language", Locale.US.getLanguage())
        .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Call call = client.newCall(request);
Response response = call.execute();
String responseBody = response.body().string();
System.out.println(responseBody);

Gson gson = new Gson();
List<MonsterJobJson> resultMonster = gson.fromJson(
        responseBody, new TypeToken<List<MonsterJobJson>>() {
        }.getType());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough reputation to just comment.

You might look at `div.mux-search-results`. It seems to have some attributes that describe how to load more results, and total number of results to display per page and total. Some attributes that seemed related listed below;

- `data-results-page="1"`
- `Data-results-url="https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/pagination/?q=java&amp;where=usa&amp;stpage=1&amp;isDynamicPage=true&amp;isMKPagination=true"`
- `data-results-per-page="25"`
- `data-results-total="250"`
- `data-total-search-results="61503"`
- `data-results-max="250"`

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! You are a lifesaver! It seems very likely to be the answer I've been looking for! Because when I tried to search for `java` in `moscow` and got 8 results, the `data-results-total` was `8` as well. Thanks, bbbbbb! I'm going to test it out and if that field is indeed how they do it, accept your answer!